# F# image manipulation performance problem

Tags: performance, image-processing, f#

I am currently trying to improve the performance of an F# program to make it as fast as its C# equivalent. The program does apply a filter array to a buffer of pixels. Access to memory is always done using pointers.

Here is the C# code which is applied to each pixel of an image:

```
unsafe private static byte getPixelValue(byte* buffer, double* filter, int filterLength, double filterSum)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filterLength; ++i)
    {
        sum += (*buffer) * (*filter);
        ++buffer;
        ++filter;
    }

    sum = sum / filterSum;

    if (sum > 255) return 255;
    if (sum < 0) return 0;
    return (byte) sum;
}
```

The F# code looks like this and takes three times as long as the C# program:

```
let getPixelValue (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filterData:nativeptr<float>) filterLength filterSum : byte =

    let rec accumulatePixel (acc:float) (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filter:nativeptr<float>) i = 
        if i > 0 then
            let newAcc = acc + (float (NativePtr.read buffer) * (NativePtr.read filter))
            accumulatePixel newAcc (NativePtr.add buffer 1) (NativePtr.add filter 1) (i-1)
        else
            acc

    let acc = (accumulatePixel 0.0 buffer filterData filterLength) / filterSum                

    match acc with
        | _ when acc > 255.0 -> 255uy
        | _ when acc < 0.0 -> 0uy
        | _ -> byte acc
```

Using mutable Variables and a for loop in F# does result in the same speed as using recursion. All Projects are configured to run in Release Mode with Code Optimization turned on.

How could the performance of the F# version be improved?

**EDIT:**

The bottleneck seems to be in `(NativePtr.get buffer offset)`. If I replace this code with a fixed value and also replace the corresponding code in the C# version with a fixed value, I get about the same speed for both programs. In fact, in C# the speed does not change at all, but in F# it makes a huge difference.

Can this behaviour possibly be changed or is it rooted deeply in the architecture of F#?

**EDIT 2:**

I refactored the code again to use for-loops. The execution speed remains the same:

```
let mutable acc <- 0.0
let mutable f <- filterData
let mutable b <- tBuffer
for i in 1 .. filter.FilterLength do
    acc <- acc + (float (NativePtr.read b)) * (NativePtr.read f)
    f <- NativePtr.add f 1
    b <- NativePtr.add b 1
```

If I compare the IL code of a version that uses `(NativePtr.read b)` and another version that is the same except that it uses a fixed value `111uy` instead of reading it from the pointer, Only the following lines in the IL code change:

`111uy` has IL-Code `ldc.i4.s 0x6f` (0.3 seconds)

`(NativePtr.read b)` has IL-Code lines  `ldloc.s b` and `ldobj uint8` (1.4 seconds)

For comparison: C# does the filtering in 0.4 seconds.

The fact that reading the filter does not impact performance while reading from the image buffer does is somehow confusing. Before I filter a line of the image I copy the line into a buffer that has the length of a line. That's why the read operations are not spread all over the image but are within this buffer, which has a size of about 800 bytes.

Comment: Based on your most recent comment, I wonder if the fact that the C# compiler uses `ldind.u1` instead of `ldobj uint8` (which is the semantically equivalent IL that F# uses) makes a difference.  You could try running ildasm on the F# executable, replacing `ldobj uint8` with `ldind.u1`, and running ilasm on it to see if the performance differs.

Comment: I replaced it but there was no difference. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we look at the actual IL code of the inner loop which traverses both buffers in parallel generated by C# compiler (relevant part):

```
L_0017: ldarg.0 
L_0018: ldc.i4.1 
L_0019: conv.i 
L_001a: add 
L_001b: starg.s buffer
L_001d: ldarg.1 
L_001e: ldc.i4.8 
L_001f: conv.i 
L_0020: add
```

and F# compiler:

```
L_0017: ldc.i4.1 
L_0018: conv.i 
L_0019: sizeof uint8
L_001f: mul 
L_0020: add 
L_0021: ldarg.2 
L_0022: ldc.i4.1 
L_0023: conv.i 
L_0024: sizeof float64
L_002a: mul 
L_002b: add
```

we'll notice that while C# code uses only `add` operator while F# needs both `mul` and `add`. But obviously on each step we only need to increment pointers (by 'sizeof byte' and 'sizeof float' values respectively), not to calculate address (addrBase + (sizeof byte)) F# `mul` is unnecessary (it always multiplies by 1).

The cause for that is that C# defines `++` operator for pointers while F# provides only `add : nativeptr<'T> -> int -> nativeptr<'T>` operator:

```
[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
let inline add (x : nativeptr<'a>) (n:int) : nativeptr<'a> = to_nativeint x + nativeint n * (# "sizeof !0" type('a) : nativeint #) |> of_nativeint
```

So it's not "rooted deeply" in F#, it's just that `module NativePtr` lacks `inc` and `dec` functions.

Btw, I suspect the above sample could be written in a more concise manner if the arguments were passed as arrays instead of raw pointers.

**UPDATE:**

So does the following code have only 1% speed up (it seems to generate very similar to C# IL):

```
let getPixelValue (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filterData:nativeptr<float>) filterLength filterSum : byte =

    let rec accumulatePixel (acc:float) (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filter:nativeptr<float>) i = 
        if i > 0 then
            let newAcc = acc + (float (NativePtr.read buffer) * (NativePtr.read filter))
            accumulatePixel newAcc (NativePtr.ofNativeInt <| (NativePtr.toNativeInt buffer) + (nativeint 1)) (NativePtr.ofNativeInt <| (NativePtr.toNativeInt filter) + (nativeint 8)) (i-1)
        else
            acc

    let acc = (accumulatePixel 0.0 buffer filterData filterLength) / filterSum                

    match acc with
        | _ when acc > 255.0 -> 255uy
        | _ when acc < 0.0 -> 0uy
        | _ -> byte acc
```

Another thought: it might also depend on the number of calls to getPixelValue your test does (F# splits this function into two methods while C# does it in one).

Is it possible that you post your testing code here?

Regarding array - I'd expect the code be at least more concise (and not `unsafe`).

**UPDATE #2:**

Looks like the actual bottleneck here is `byte->float` conversion.

C#:

```
L_0003: ldarg.1 
L_0004: ldind.u1 
L_0005: conv.r8
```

F#:

```
L_000c: ldarg.1 
L_000d: ldobj uint8
L_0012: conv.r.un 
L_0013: conv.r8
```

For some reason F# uses the following path: `byte->float32->float64` while C# does only `byte->float64`. Not sure why is that, but with the following hack my F# version runs with the same speed as C# on gradbot test sample (BTW, thanks **gradbot** for the test!):

```
let inline preadConvert (p : nativeptr<byte>) = (# "conv.r8" (# "ldobj !0" type (byte) p : byte #) : float #)
let inline pinc (x : nativeptr<'a>) : nativeptr<'a> = NativePtr.toNativeInt x + (# "sizeof !0" type('a) : nativeint #) |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt

let rec accumulatePixel_ed (acc, buffer, filter,  i) = 
        if i > 0 then
            accumulatePixel_ed
                (acc + (preadConvert buffer) * (NativePtr.read filter),
                (pinc buffer),
                (pinc filter),
                (i-1))
        else
            acc
```

Results:

```
    adrian 6374985677.162810 1408.870900 ms
   gradbot 6374985677.162810 1218.908200 ms
        C# 6374985677.162810 227.832800 ms
 C# Offset 6374985677.162810 224.921000 ms
   mutable 6374985677.162810 1254.337300 ms
     ed'ka 6374985677.162810 227.543100 ms
```

**LAST UPDATE**
It turned out that we can achieve the same speed even without any hacks:

```
let rec accumulatePixel_ed_last (acc, buffer, filter,  i) = 
        if i > 0 then
            accumulatePixel_ed_last
                (acc + (float << int16 <| NativePtr.read buffer) * (NativePtr.read filter),
                (NativePtr.add buffer 1),
                (NativePtr.add filter 1),
                (i-1))
        else
            acc
```

All we need to do is to convert `byte` into, say `int16` and then into `float`. This way 'costly' `conv.r.un` instruction will be avoided.

PS Relevant conversion code from "prim-types.fs" :

```
let inline float (x: ^a) = 
    (^a : (static member ToDouble : ^a -> float) (x))
     when ^a : float     = (# "" x  : float #)
     when ^a : float32   = (# "conv.r8" x  : float #)
     // [skipped]
     when ^a : int16     = (# "conv.r8" x  : float #)
     // [skipped]
     when ^a : byte       = (# "conv.r.un conv.r8" x  : float #)
     when ^a : decimal    = (System.Convert.ToDouble((# "" x : decimal #)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting idea! I created my custom add function for pointers that does not use the multiplication. The speed-up is only about 1% of the total execution time. Do you think the array version would still have a high performance?

Comment: Wow! I'm really impressed :-)

Answer (score 1):

How does this compare?  It has less calls to `NativePtr`.

```
let getPixelValue (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filterData:nativeptr<float>) filterLength filterSum : byte =
    let accumulatePixel (acc:float) (buffer:nativeptr<byte>) (filter:nativeptr<float>) length = 
        let rec accumulate acc offset = 
            if offset < length then
                let newAcc = acc + (float (NativePtr.get buffer offset) * (NativePtr.get filter offset))
                accumulate newAcc (offset + 1)
            else
                acc
        accumulate acc 0

    let acc = (accumulatePixel 0.0 buffer filterData filterLength) / filterSum                

    match acc with
        | _ when acc > 255.0 -> 255uy
        | _ when acc < 0.0 -> 0uy
        | _ -> byte acc
```

F# source code of NativePtr.

```
[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
[<CompiledName("AddPointerInlined")>]
let inline add (x : nativeptr<'T>) (n:int) : nativeptr<'T> = toNativeInt x + nativeint n * (# "sizeof !0" type('T) : nativeint #) |> ofNativeInt

[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
[<CompiledName("GetPointerInlined")>]
let inline get (p : nativeptr<'T>) n = (# "ldobj !0" type ('T) (add p n) : 'T #)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea, but the performance improvement is marginal.

Comment: I think (NativePtr.get buffer offset) is about as fast as (NativePtr.read (NativePtr.add buffer offset)), probably it does the same behind the scenes...

Answer (score 1):

My results on a larger test.

```
    adrian 6374730426.098020 1561.102500 ms
   gradbot 6374730426.098020 1842.768000 ms
        C# 6374730426.098020  150.793500 ms
 C# Offset 6374730426.098020  150.318900 ms
   mutable 6374730426.098020 1446.616700 ms
```

F# test code

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Diagnostics

open AccumulatePixel
#nowarn "9"

let test size fn =
    let bufferByte = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size * 4)
    let bufferFloat = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size * 8)

    let bi = NativePtr.ofNativeInt bufferByte
    let bf = NativePtr.ofNativeInt bufferFloat

    let random = System.Random()

    for i in 1 .. size do
        NativePtr.set bi i (byte <| random.Next() % 256)
        NativePtr.set bf i (random.NextDouble())

    let duration (f, name) =
        let stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        let time = f(0.0, bi, bf, size)
        stopWatch.Stop()
        printfn "%10s %f %f ms" name time stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

    List.iter duration fn

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal bufferFloat
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal bufferByte

let rec accumulatePixel_adrian (acc, buffer, filter, i) = 
    if i > 0 then
        let newAcc = acc + (float (NativePtr.read buffer) * (NativePtr.read filter))
        accumulatePixel_adrian (newAcc, (NativePtr.add buffer 1), (NativePtr.add filter 1), (i - 1))
    else
        acc

let accumulatePixel_gradbot (acc, buffer, filter, length) = 
    let rec accumulate acc offset = 
        if offset < length then
            let newAcc = acc + (float (NativePtr.get buffer offset) * (NativePtr.get filter offset))
            accumulate newAcc (offset + 1)
        else
            acc
    accumulate acc 0

let accumulatePixel_mutable (acc, buffer, filter, length) = 
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    let mutable f = filter
    let mutable b = buffer
    for i in 1 .. length do
        acc <- acc + (float (NativePtr.read b)) * (NativePtr.read f)
        f <- NativePtr.add f 1
        b <- NativePtr.add b 1
    acc

[
    accumulatePixel_adrian, "adrian";
    accumulatePixel_gradbot, "gradbot";
    AccumulatePixel.getPixelValue, "C#";
    AccumulatePixel.getPixelValueOffset, "C# Offset";
    accumulatePixel_mutable, "mutable";
]
|> test 100000000

System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

C# test code

```
namespace AccumulatePixel
{
    public class AccumulatePixel
    {
        unsafe public static double getPixelValue(double sum, byte* buffer, double* filter, int filterLength)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filterLength; ++i)
            {
                sum += (*buffer) * (*filter);
                ++buffer;
                ++filter;
            }

            return sum;
        }

        unsafe public static double getPixelValueOffset(double sum, byte* buffer, double* filter, int filterLength)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filterLength; ++i)
            {
                sum += buffer[i] * filter[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```